# Linux kernel crypto API callback issue

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptography

I've been trying (and struggling) to use callbacks with skciphers on the Linux kernel. Specifically, I call the function with (for example) `skcipher_request_set_callback(req, 0, my_callback_function, my_data)` but the callback function is never invoked after `crypt_encrypt()` or `crypt_decrypt()` are called. I'm using `xts(aes)` and this issue occurs regardless of whether I call `crypto_wait_req()` or not. Is there something I'm missing?

Also, to be sure, this identical issue occurs when I follow the code examples from the official documentation (for example, see here https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/crypto/api-samples.html, though I'm using 5.14.18). If I copy and paste that example code and run it, the callback function will *still*
not be invoked. Does anyone have any suggestions? The API is not well documented and this is driving me nuts, as I've already spent way too much time on this issue.

Thanks in advance! If more context is needed, let me know and I'll try to provide it.